# Redirect to action of controller using ajax call

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

I am using jquery ajax call and in controller action i want to redirect some action but when

i use redirect_to "/some_action". Then it did not redirect to my desired action please give

any  useful suggestions.

```
<%= link_to "javascript:;" ,:onclick => "admin_fun"%>
```

my jquery ajax call is

```
function admin_fun() {
  if (confirm("Are you sure you want to add?")) {
    var container = $("#trunk_detail");

    $.ajax({
      url:'/accounting/add_rule',
      type:'get',
      dataType:'html',
      processData:false,
      success:function (data) {
        container.html(data);
      }
    });
  }
}
```

my controller code is

```
def add_rule
  # do somthing

  redirect_to "/accounting/index_report"   

  render :text => "ok"
end
```

Comment: If you want to redirect on some page then you can use simple url call rather than making ajax call. Is there any specific reason to call ajax on link?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line will not give you the desired results because you can redirect or render multiple times.rather than you omit this line from controller

redirect_to "/accounting/index_report"

and in jquery ajax call on success response you can redirect to your desired action like

if (confirm("Are you sure you want to add?")) {

```
var container = $("#trunk_detail");

$.ajax({

    url:'/accounting/add_rule',

    type:'get',

    dataType:'html',

    processData:false,

    success:function (data) {

        container.html(data);

        window.location.replace("/accounting/index_report"); 

    }
});
```

}
}

And enjoying........

Answer (score 0):

You can't cause 2 responses in a rails action like that. If you check the log you are probably going to see a 'double render error' in the `add_rule` action. Why are you redirecting exactly? If you can explain your actual intention a bit more clearly then we can arrive at some code that will do that.